# decision tree:how to replace the 'NaN' to a value which can help me to fix the model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, data-analysis

the error is

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

where the error:

```
clf = clf.fit(model_train,y_train)
```

my code is below

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn import tree

Model_Dev_Val = pd.read_excel("fuckdata.xlsx")
target = Model_Dev_Val[['source_2']]
model_train, model_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Model_Dev_Val, target,test_size = 0.5, random_state = 40,stratify = target)

imp = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN',strategy = 'mean',axis=0)
model_train = imp.fit(model_train)
y_train = imp.fit(y_train)

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(model_train,y_train)
clf.predict(model_test)
```

Looks like my 'NAN' doesnt turn to 'mean'.Anyway,help.I have been searching it all day.THX

Answer (score 1):

Try using `imp.fit_transform` instead of just `imp.fit` - the latter just returns a fitted model, not an actual new array.

Comment: I will do it later. Thx ,on my way home

Comment: Okay? We posted twenty seconds apart... I wasn't trying to steal your glory or anything...